# Derefrencing pointer to incomplete type in TCP client? (C)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm trying to make a server and a client (TCP) in C that will function as a simple chat system. I know very little about such things and have been referencing [this server example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm) and [this client example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_client_example.htm)
.

Note: I changed bzero() and bcopy() to memset() and memcpy() as my limited research suggested, but the error occured in both situations. Apart from this, my own client differs only in format and ouput from the linked example.

```
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent * server;

    char buffer[256];

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0)  { perror("failed_socket_open"); exit(1); }

    server = (struct hostent *)gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"host isn't real, everything is a lie\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy( (char*)server->h_addr,(char*) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length );
```

Upon this line (37):

```
memcpy( (char*)server->h_addr, (char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length );
```

I am told:

```
client.c:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
client.c:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

It appears this is a result of not having sufficient information on the size that server->h_length is supposed to provide. Is there some library function I'm missing, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`struct hostent`, which `server` is, is defined in `netdb.h`. As you do not include this header, you're dereferencing a pointer to an incomplete type when doing `server->`.